# How can I transfer my docker image to another computer?

Tags: docker

I created an online shop website in a docker container and want to transfer the image including all my work to another computer. How can I do that?

Comment: Backup and restore your Docker container, see for example: https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-backup/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need to save the docker image as a tar file:
`docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>`

Then copy the image to your target machine and then run:
`docker load -i <path to image tar file>`

Comment: Don't I need to commit my  changes first with `docker commit -p container-ID backup-name`

Comment: yes, if you want to create a new image with the changes on the existing image ,then you need to commit

Answer (score 0):

it depends if all the data is in your image or if you use volumes

see about docker volumes this doc

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

you can `docker save`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

copy the tar archive, and then

`docker load`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

and then deal with the data in the volumes if you had